# Import a PhoneGap App into Dreamweaver 6

Tags: eclipse, cordova, dreamweaver

I am trying to import a PhoneGap APP I was previously working on in Eclipse into DW6.

I created a new site in DW and pointed it to the APPs folder. When I go to build the APP and re download it for testing. It seems to be building the wrong APP. The APP shows an alert that says "PhoneGap is working" and on the page it says "Hey, it's PhoneGap!"

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Dreamweaver cs5.5 so I may be off base, but it sounds to me like your app is using Phonegap's original tutorial index page. Take a look and make sure that you don't have the incorrect index in your DW site.

BTW, have you figured out how to build a DW app without using Adobe's pay service? AFAIKT, DW 6 doesn't allow developers to build an app without paying Adobe. I'm not upgrading. I like controlling my own applications. IMHO, there are too many middle men already.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and realized it's because PhoneGap will utilize the Site files in DW. In the bottom right section of DW, you should see local files for your Site. You can select the drop down on the current site to go to manage sites and select a New Site and point to your DIR holding the app files.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I did do this already and still have the same issue.